# how to get the users current location address in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I would like to display the current location of the user address automatically.
How to get the current location of the user in flutter?

When I was trying to run sample program, it shows me the error as

> [ERROR:flutter/shell/platform/android/platform_view_android_jni.cc(40)] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v4/util/ArraySet;

[image]

Comment: You can [edit] your question and append additional info there

Comment: Try to use [GeoLocation](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator/versions/1.0.0), listen to it you will get the position, with that position you can extract latitude, longitude

Comment: i am using the geo location and i am getting the latitude and longitude, now if i want to display the address of lat and lag what i have to do?